# MYSQL: Adding fields which are aliases and have operations

Tags: mysql

Good day! I want to add fields "duration and dials"

Here is my mysql query:

```
select
  u.dialer_display_name,
  u.dialer_ext,
  sum(dl.duration/60) as duration,
  count(dl.dial_id) as dials 
from leads.dial_log as dl 
left join leads.users as u on u.user_id=dl.user_id 
where date(dl.dial_date) = date(now()) 
and u.dialer_display_name != '' 
group by dl.user_id order by dials DESC
```

So what I want to achieve is to add duration and dials and alias them as mets.

Something like:

> select sum(duration+dials) as mets

How to build the query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the two terms making the respective columns:

```
SELECT u.dialer_display_name,
       u.dialer_ext,
       SUM(dl.duration/60) AS duration,
       COUNT(dl.dial_id) AS dials,
       SUM(dl.duration/60) + COUNT(dl.dial_id) AS mets    -- here is your column
FROM leads.dial_log AS dl 
LEFT JOIN leads.users AS u
    ON u.user_id = dl.user_id 
WHERE DATE(dl.dial_date) = DATE(NOW()) AND
      u.dialer_display_name != '' 
GROUP BY dl.user_id
ORDER BY dials DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to repeat the logic, because you cannot re-use the aliases:

```
select u.dialer_display_name, u.dialer_ext,
       sum(dl.duration/60) as duration,
       count(dl.dial_id) as dials,
       (sum(dl.duration/60) + count(dl.dial_id) ) as mets 
from leads.dial_log dl join
     leads.users u
     on u.user_id = dl.user_id 
where dl.dial_date >= curdate() and
      dl.dial_date < date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day) and
      u.dialer_display_name <> '' 
group by u.dialer_display_name, u.dialer_ext
order by dials DESC;
```

Notes:

- The comparison in the `where` using `date()` has been replaced with two comparisons.  This allows the use of an index (if available).
- `date(now())` has been replaced with `curdate()`.
- The `group by` has been modified to match the columns in the `select`.
- The `left join` has been replaced with an inner join.  The `where` clause undoes the `left join`, so don't be misleading.
- The new column has been added.

I will also say that `count(dl.dial_id)` seems strange.  I suspect you want one of the following:

```
count(distinct dl.dial_id)
count(*)
```

Comment: Why would a correct answer attract an anonymous downvote?